# Changing Account Dashboard

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, customer-account, phtml

I recently changed the list of information that's provided to a user within their Account Dashboard.

Within the `/theme/template/customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml` file I added the following lines above where the Email is shown:

```
<?php echo $this->__('Username: ') . $this->escapeHtml(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getUsername()) ?><br/>

<?php echo $this->__('Birthday: ') . $this->escapeHtml ($this->getCustomer()->getDob()) ?><br/>

<?php echo $this->__('Gender: ') . $this->escapeHtml ($this->getCustomer()->getGender()) ?>
```

The username works fine, as do the Birthday and Gender codes. However, the Birthday and Gender are presented as they are shown in the database.

Birthday is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Gender is `1` or `2` since the value in the database is INT instead of text.

Is there any way I can change how these are displayed within `info.phtml` without changing fields in the `eav_attribute` table?

For instance, `MM-DD-YYYY` and `Male` or `Female`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below Mentioned code in your file:

```
    <?php 
        echo $this->__('Birthday: ') . date('m-d-Y', strtotime($this->getCustomer()->getDob())); 
        echo '<br>';
        if($this->getCustomer()->getGender() == 1)
        {
        echo $this->__('Gender: ') . 'Male'; 
        }
       else if($this->getCustomer()->getGender() == 2){
            echo $this->__('Gender: ') . 'Female'; 
        }       

    ?>
```